# Can this be rewritten without a subquery?

Tags: sql, sql-server

The where clause in the select statement inside the join would need those values to be passed in without being hard coded but I can't just place TN.id1 = b.id1, TN.id2 = b.id2, etc... inside that statement as it can't be bound.

```
SELECT 
a.DateCreated, 
*
from B1 b
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT 
    MIN(GGI.DATE) DateCreated,
    GI.TEXT, 
    TN.ID1, 
    TN.ID2, 
    TN.ID3 
FROM TABLENAME TN
LEFT JOIN GITEM GI ON 
GI.SEQ_NBR = TN.SEQ_NBR
AND GI.STATUS = 'Approved'
WHERE 
    TN.ID1 = 'AP17' 
    AND TN.ID2 = '0' 
    AND TN.ID3 = '1'
GROUP BY GI.TEXT, TN.ID1, TN.ID2, TN.ID3
) a ON 
b.ID1 = a.ID1 
AND b.ID2 = a.ID2
AND b.ID3 = a.ID3
WHERE   b.ID1 = 'AP17' 
    AND b.ID2 = '0' 
    AND b.ID3 = '1'
```

Can this be rewritten without a subquery?

I am trying to do something like this(excerpt from above query):

```
    WHERE 
    TN.ID1 = b.ID1
    AND TN.ID2 = b.ID2 
    AND TN.ID3 = b.ID3
GROUP BY GI.TEXT, TN.ID1, TN.ID2, TN.ID3
```

Sample data:

Table "Table1" in this table I only care about the first row.

```
ID1  ID2 ID3  Text
AP17  0   1    Red
AP17  0   2    Green
AP17  0   3    Blue
```

Table "Table2" - From this table I need to use all the "SEQ_NBR" rows that match the first row in the last table to get the data in the next table.

```
ID1 ID2 ID3  SEQ_NBR
AP17  0   1     1
AP17  0   1     2
AP17  0   1     3
AP17  0   2     4
```

Table "Table3" - I want to create rows for each different type of "Item" with the earliest date were the Status was set to "A"

```
SEQ_NBR Status   Item         DATE
  1       I      APPLE     12/05/17
  2       A      APPLE     12/10/17
  3       A      APPLE     12/13/17
  1       A      Cup       12/05/17
  2       A      Cup       12/10/17
  3       A      Cup       12/13/17
  1       I      Item3     12/05/17
  2       I      Item3     12/10/17
  3       A      Item3     12/13/17
```

Data I'm pulling would look like so which would always have the earliest date in "Table3" where the status was set to "A":

```
DateCreated  ID1  ID2 ID3  Item
12/10/17     AP17  0   1   Apple
12/05/17     AP17  0   1   Cup
12/13/17     AP17  0   1   Item3
```

Comment: Can you provide some DDL and Sample data please? The answer is likely yes, but we really need something to work with.

Comment: AND b.ID2 = a.ID2 AND b.ID2 = a.ID2 ?

Comment: What are you really trying to solve here? Just doing this without a subquery may not be a good approach at all.

Comment: @Larnu I've added some sample data if it helps.

Comment: @SeanLange I also added an excerpt that shows what I'm trying to do with the query.I'd like to be able to pull the values inside the subquery based on what the b1 table is using without having to go in and change the hard-coded values.

Comment: No I mean try to explain what you query is trying to do. Your explanation does not make much sense. Why do you only get that 1 row? Help us understand the problem and we can help you find a solution. I am ignoring your query and focusing only on the data you provided. It is not clear at all.

Comment: It is in fact redundant what you need since outer `WHERE` clause still filters on exact values. In fact, doesn't your current query output your desired results?

Comment: @SeanLange, I've updated the data and ignoring the query that is what I'm trying to get to. Is this better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure this is a basic aggregate query. This returns the desired output for the sample data provided.

```
select DateCreated = MIN(MyDate)
    , t2.ID1
    , t2.ID2
    , t2.ID3
    , t3.Item
from Table1 t1
join Table2 t2 on t2.ID1 = t1.ID1
                and t2.ID2 = t1.ID2
join Table3 t3 on t3.SEQ_NBR = t2.SEQ_NBR
                and t3.Status = 'A'
group by t2.ID1
    , t2.ID2
    , t2.ID3
    , t3.Item
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could rewrite like this. I'm guessing a bit since it's not SUPER clear that all the requirements are listed since you say "Rewrite my query to not use a subquery above" and your SQL just fetches a particular result by id1, id2, and id3. Then you give us the tables and the requirements change to "which would always have the earliest date in "Table3" where the status was set to "A"" which isn't what your SQL is doing. Given that second requirement and ignoring the first:

```
SELECT
    git.date,
    table3.id1,
    table3.id2,
    table3.id3,
    b1.text
FROM
    gitem as git
    INNER JOIN table3 ON
        git.seq_nbr = table3.seq_nbr
    INNER JOIN b1 ON
        table3.id1 = b1.id1 AND
        table3.id2 = b1.id2 AND
        table3.id3 = b1.id3
WHERE
    git.status = 'A' AND
    git.date = (SELECT min(date) FROM gitem WHERE status='A')
```

This will pull the color, id1, id2, id3, and date where the date is the first date with a status of 'A'. It seems a little clearer about what the query is doing, but it still uses a subquery. It's just that subquery is in place only to find the right `gitem` record according to your requirements.